# What logical function should i use to do a union of two raster files in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis

The files are :
DEM and roads. For the following i did euclid distance and then reclass. Now i need to know with what logical function to combine them

```
                   elevation   rank
               DEM < 300        10
               DEM > 300        0


                     distance    rank
proximity to roads < 2000        10 
proximity to roads > 2000        5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is better to use r.series. You have 4 files with different values (as I can see). You have to choose the function according to what you want to have. I suppose you want the files with the value 10 "up" the others from "behind". Perhaps you can use the r.series twice. First for the DEM files and then for the roads using the maximum function. For the results you can try r.patch or r.series again.

Comment: is it possible to do it simultaneously? i believe it is in the r.series to put dem and roads and do maximum for both.

Comment: Yes.With maximum you would have a file with value 10 up, 5 and 0. r.series is very powerful and useful !

Answer (score 0):

TRy to use :

```
     r.patch
```

This is the documentaion  : http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.patch.html

Comment: So far, i was thinking about doing it through r.series and having toruble deciding which logical function to use. Can you help with that?

Comment: you can use r.path to union several raster, but to reclasify raster you can use r.reclass or mapalgebra